# Owl Carousel 2 not visible but no errors

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel-2

I have been trying for some time to get the Owl Carousel 2 to work on my dev site. I've used it countless times before so clearly I'm doing something silly. I can get v1.x to work.

http://www.creativethings.nz/web/the-house

I have no errors, I am pretty sure it's essentially working but just not showing. Maybe a CSS issue, but I'm using the stock CSS from Owl Carousel 2.

In the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl2/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl2/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

Mid-body:

```
<div id="gallery" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div><img src="web/images/gallery/sd.jpg"/></div>                                                                                                                                
<div><img src="web/images/gallery/sd.jpg"/></div>                                                                                
</div>
```

At the end of the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="owl2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>  
<script> 
$(window).on('load',function() { 
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
</script>
```

I observed that by inspecting in Chrome and changing the CSS for .owl-stage-outer to overflow:visible, it shows (both) images in the slideshow alongside each-other. Can anyone help diagnose and resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "items" option when initializing your carousel.

```
    $(window).on('load',function() { 
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({items:1});
    });
```

Working JSFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly7h539z/1/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This was 50% of the problem. I added the {items:1} in and it still didn't show. I added a clear:both to the block before it and it worked. I took out the {items:1} and it showed on the page, but incorrectly with two rather than just 1 image. Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: Glad I was able to contribute.